# @routeprovider angularjs and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a MVC View (Say Index) where I am loading multiple views via AngularJS and I have defined the angular route something like

```
angular.module("myModule", []).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/Home/View1', { templateUrl: '/ngViews/View1.html', controller: 'Controller1' });
$routeProvider.when('/Home/View2', { templateUrl: '/ngviews/View2.html', controller: 'Controller2' });  
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); });
```

Now I want if there is link like /Home/Details (or Test/AnotherAction )which is not provided using $routeprovider then it should call MVC action. Please suggest the best way to handle it.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: are you able to access html pages from mvc views folder?

Comment: I have created another folder ngViews where I have all the templates